# Recovering MySql root@localhost user in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I accidantally deleted the user root@localhost, which is, as I later found out needed for mysql to work and now, I cannot login with root, even if the password is correct. I tried running mysql ins afe mode:

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

and then loging in as root with no password and going into the mysql database, where I should execute:

```
create user root@localhost;
```

and then:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' with grant option;
commit;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

but when I try to create the user with the above command I get:

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Any suggestions how to solve this? Help is greatly appeciated, thanks!

EDIT:SOLUTION

Thanks! This solved my problem:

> INSERT INTO `mysql`.`user`(`Host`, `User`, `Password`, `Select_priv`,
>   `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`,
>   `Drop_priv`, `Reload_priv`, `Shutdown_priv`, `Process_priv`,
>   `File_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `References_priv`, `Index_priv`,
>   `Alter_priv`, `Show_db_priv`, `Super_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`,
>   `Lock_tables_priv`, `Execute_priv`, `Repl_slave_priv`,
>   `Repl_client_priv`, `Create_view_priv`, `Show_view_priv`,
>   `Create_routine_priv`, `Alter_routine_priv`, `Create_user_priv`,
>   `ssl_type`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`, `x509_subject`,
>   `max_questions`, `max_updates`, `max_connections`,
>   `max_user_connections`) VALUES ('%', 'root',
>   PASSWORD('NEW_PASSWORD_HERE'), 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y',
>   'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y',
>   'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0');

To restore the privileges for event and trigger I had to access another user with 'all' privileges, luckily I had one, but probably isn't possible without one.

Comment: `INSERT` him in the `mysql.user` table, set `Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y'`, restart, see what it does.

Comment: I'm affraid this will only restore the privileges on existing root users, but I need to re-create root@localhost

Comment: @user1850912 see if my answer will help you.

Comment: What does `INSERT`-ing into `mysql.user` do that is _not_ creating a user?

Comment: @Wrikken Because with the mysql root user deleted, the grant option wont work even starting it in skip-grant-tables. You have to manually insert the row to recreate it.

Comment: @PanamaJack: well, what do you think I mean when I say `INSERT` it? You answer holds the clue: `INSERT INTO mysql.user`... Which is what I'm saying. I'm not disagreeing, I'm frustrated that apparently saying `INSERT` does not ring a bell & it needs to be spelled out explicitly apparently ;)

Comment: @Wrikken Oh I get what you're saying. Yes, but I was trying to provide a more complete answer because the root user would still not be completely restored how it should be if all the options aren't updated and he might not know to fix them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should recover it as opposed to resetting.

Stop mysql server.

edit the my.cnf to include the skip grants

```
[mysqld] 
skip_grant_tables
```

Start mysql. Then login to mysql by just using `mysql` command from the prompt. and insert this query making sure to update the password where it says `new password here`.

> INSERT INTO `mysql`.`user`(`Host`, `User`, `Password`, `Select_priv`,
>   `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`,
>   `Drop_priv`, `Reload_priv`, `Shutdown_priv`, `Process_priv`,
>   `File_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `References_priv`, `Index_priv`,
>   `Alter_priv`, `Show_db_priv`, `Super_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`,
>   `Lock_tables_priv`, `Execute_priv`, `Repl_slave_priv`,
>   `Repl_client_priv`, `Create_view_priv`, `Show_view_priv`,
>   `Create_routine_priv`, `Alter_routine_priv`, `Create_user_priv`,
>   `ssl_type`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`, `x509_subject`,
>   `max_questions`, `max_updates`, `max_connections`,
>   `max_user_connections`) VALUES ('%', 'root',
>   PASSWORD('NEW_PASSWORD_HERE'), 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y',
>   'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y',
>   'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0');

After running the query, stop mysql and remove the skip grants from my.cnf then restart mysql

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to login via ssh? in console type mysql -uroot
After that :
use mysql;
SELECT* FROM `user`; to see what are the columns
And do an INSERT INTO `user`....